# Handling CometD channels in Angular 2 is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cometd

After some baby steps in Angular2 and Typescript I decided to write application that uses plain javascript CometD library. This app should just get data from CometD channel and somehow present them to the user.

So basically, I've created following simple component with reference to CometD js library.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as cometd from '../cometd/cometd';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

   title = 'app works!';
   cometD: any;

  constructor() {
    console.log("Starting cometD service ...");
    this.cometD = new cometd.CometD();
    this.cometD.configure({ url: '/services/cometd', logLevel: 'debug', requestHeaders: { "userID": 555 } });
    this.title = "CometD demo";
    this.cometD.handshake();
    this.subscribe()
  }


  subscribe() {
    this.cometD.subscribe('/mychannel', (message)=> this.mychannelHandler(message));
  }

  mychannelHandler(message) {
    console.log("MESSAGE FROM SERVER RECIEVED: " + message + ", data: " + message.data);
    this.title = message.data;
  }


}
```

When I run this, there is debug messages in console from cometD - that the connection is OK, there has been added subscription to the channel, and some output, that there are some data coming. BUT.

**The mychannelHandler is never called. The message is never passed into console and the title variable is not set. What am I missing ?**

Thank you very much for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `this.mychannelHandler` here. Your callback to `subscribe` does not call `this.mychannelHandler`:

```
subscribe() {
  this.cometD.subscribe('/mychannel', () => this.mychannelHandler); 
}
```

Change it to:

```
this.cometD.subscribe('/mychannel', this.mychannelHandler); 
// OR
this.cometD.subscribe('/mychannel', (message) => this.mychannelHandler(message));
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it, but it still does not work :(